# Create popups with multiple WFS layers

Tags: javascript, wfs, openlayers

I am having trouble displaying popups on points plotted on my OpenLayers 3 map from two different WFS sources. Both are PostGIS tables coming from GeoServer.

```
var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup();
map.addOverlay(popup);
map.on('click', function(evt) {
    // Hide existing popup and reset it's offset
    popup.hide();
    popup.setOffset([0, 0]);

    // Attempt to find a marker from the planningAppsLayer
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        return feature;
    });
    if (feature) {
        var coord = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        var props = feature.getProperties();
        var info = "<h2><a href='" + props.addr + "'>" + props.addr + "</a></h2>";
            info += "<p>" + coord + "</p>";
            info += "<p>Status: " + props.addr + "   " + props.stuff + "</p>";
        // Offset the popup so it points at the middle of the marker not the tip
        popup.setOffset([0, -22]);
        popup.show(coord, info);

    }
```

Addr comes from the layer fpal, and stuff comes from the layer planningAppsLayer. I was wondering if there was a way to create popups with completely different popup for the information from each layer. Not sure if I am making sense.